# A question regarding electric field and charges inside a conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

[image]

In this figure there is a positive point charge in the cavity and it creates an electric field, this polarises the charges in the conductor and the negative charges move towards the cavity where the positive point charge is. There is excess positive charge on the outer surface and excess negative charge near the part where the cavity begins but I learn't in school that excess charges reside at the surface but the excess negative charge is near the centre and not at the surface.Is there any explanation for this? I would love a simple explanation as I am in the 12th grade.

Comment: It's still "near the surface", except it's in the inner surface of the shell.

Comment: The object shown has two surfaces. Both types of charge are on surfaces and not in the bulk of the conductor.